# External interaction with a controlled component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (**MyComponent**) which has two text fields. Entering in text in the top text field, changes the text in the second field (See diagram).

I is a simple controlled component using onChange() and setState().

Now I have a textfield in an outer component. I want to listen on the changes to this text field, and update the same display textfield in **MyComponent**.

[image]

Basically I have two text fields that can update the same textfield, however one is in the component, whereas the other one is outside the component.

What is the best way to do this?

I feel like it is a pretty simple thing to do, however I found myself going down some complicated jouneys trying to find a solution.

Things i looked at :

- componentWillReceiveProps  - deprecated
- componentDidUpdate - seems good, but this happens after the render so it cannot be used
- getDerivedStateFromProps - this is kind of where I am most leaning towards

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is your solution....
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7zbxti